# SVG <text> gets misaligned on Arabic version of site?

Tags: svg, arabic

I have a complex svg layout that's made of elements like `<rect>`, `<path>`, `<text>`, etc.

The svg displays perfectly on the English version of the website, but on the Arabic version of the site, all the  elements are moved slightly to the right.

I have compared the svg code between the Arabic and English versions just to be sure, and all the transform-matrixes are the same.

Comment: Adding a piece of example code could help a lot at getting answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was caused by the rtl setting in the `<html>` tag (dir = rtl).

I fixed the issue by setting dir=ltr to the svg container element. (Note, it did not work if dir=ltr was set to the `<svg>` directly).